# Trying to add uv project modifier on eye but eye gets stretched up and down

Tags: animation, texturing, uv

[image]
Eye before applying uv project modifier

[image]

Eye after applying uv modifier to empty bone.

As you can see, I don't know why but eyes are stretched out from top to bottom...

[image]

And when I move the empty slightly to the left, it goes like this...

[image]

UV setting is set to like this.

Why is this happening? I'm so confused... Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the texture isn't projecting right may be due to the lack of Coordinate and Mapping nodes, like so:

[image: Mapping nodes]

With the Texture Coordinate set to UV, the UV Project and UV Warp modifiers should start functioning properly. You can quickly add these nodes in with the built-in Node Wrangler add-on, using <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> after selecting the image texture node.

Note that in this example, I have the X and Y scale on the Mapping node set to -1, in order to flip the centered texture along those axis. Those properties can be animated as well, but the eye rig should be able to take over from there.